# What is "backup mode" in postgresql?

Tags: backup, postgresql

I am in the process of setting up a standby server for a PostgreSQL 9.3 install. I was looking to use `pg_basebackup` to get the initial starting point for the standby server. However, the documentation for `pg_basebackup` mentions that it will "[make] sure the system is automatically put in and out of backup mode". I can't seem to find what "backup mode" is, or what effects that will have on the production server.

The documentation for `pg_basebackup` does mention that the backup is "taken without affecting other clients to the database", but I need to be certain that "backup mode" won't do anything unexpected to the production server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In and out of backup mode means that it will execute the `pg_start_backup()` function at the beginning and `pg_stop_backup()` at the end.

They're described at [Backup Control Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-BACKUP) in the documentation.

The effect of `pg_start_backup()` on the production server is a possible I/O spike caused by checkpointing (applying the transaction log also named xlog or WAL files to the final data files).
This may be mitigated by the option `--checkpoint=fast|spread` but it's already `spread` by default according to [pg_basebackup manpage](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgbasebackup.html).

"Not affecting other clients" means that SQL programs can continue all operations without restriction during the backup. Possibly with a loss in performance due to the I/O load caused by the backup itself, but there's no way to avoid that.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did read a bit on the page for `pg_start_backup()` but still didn't feel very confident.